# chrome Extension manifes tV3 error - violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: jsonp, content-security-policy

I am trying to send data to server in the jsonp method from the chrome extension I am developing.
However, it worked fine in manifest V2, but the following error occurs in manifestV3.
Please help me.

Refused to load the script 'https://www.example.com/interface/add?a=dataLayer&b=1234' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

```
manifest.json v2
  "content_security_policy": "script-src https:///www.example.com/ 'self'; object-src 'self'",

manifest.json v3 // "script-src https:///www.example.com/ 'self' occured error. 
  "content_security_policy": {
  "extension_pages":"script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"                     
  },

popup.js
        $.ajax({
          dataType        : 'jsonp'
          , url           : 'https://www.example.com/interface/add'
          ,contentType    : 'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8'
          ,jsonpCallback  : 'addCallback'
          ,data: {'a':'a','b':'b'}
          ,success   :  function(res, textStatus, jqXHR){
              console.log(res);
          }
          ,error               : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              console.log('fail');
          }
     }); 

function addCallback(res){
//  $('#_result').text(JSON.stringify(res));
      console.log("succ+++++" + res);
} 


'''
```